# Changing highlight colours of headings when using outline-minor-mode

Tags: outline

I would like to change the highlight colours of headings when using `outline-minor-mode`.

Have composed the following which is giving `wrong-number-of-arguments`
for `outline-map-region`.  I have included `beg` and `end` with
`(font-lock-flush)` but the colours are not taking effect.

```el
(defun heading-tyface ()
  "Set foreground colour for headings in `outline-minor-mode'."
  (interactive)

  (let ( (beg (point-min))
         (end (point-max)) )
 
 (outline-map-region
   (lambda ()
     (let* ( ($hglevl (funcall outline-level))
             ($tyface (cond
                       ((= $hglevl 1) '(:foreground "red"))
                       ((= $hglevl 2) '(:foreground "blue"))
                       ((= $hglevl 3) '(:foreground "green"))
                       (t '(:foreground "white")))) )
       ;;--------------------------
       (when (looking-at outline-regexp)
         (put-text-property (point-at-bol) (point-at-eol)
                            '$tyface $tyface))))

     beg end)

    (font-lock-flush)))
```

Comment: Compare the documentation (`C-h f outline-map-region`) with what you're trying to do.

Comment: I simply pass the function, and `BEG` and `END` should be defaulted for the whole buffer.

Comment: I have now added `BEG` and `END` as `(point-min)` and `(point-max)`.  But the colour scheme is not taking effect.

Comment: This questions was also posted to the [emacs help mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2023-06/msg00115.html).

Comment: Using the buffer `beg` and `end` together with `(font-lock-flush)` does not seem to be enough.

Comment: What can I do to solve this problem with `outline-map-region` ?